# Compilation error 'The Method setRadius(int) is undefined for the type Shape'

Tags: java, arrays, loops, class, object

```
Shape[] sa = new Shape[10];
for(int i = 0; i < sa.length; i=i+2) {
    sa[i] = new Circle();
    sa[i].setRadius(2);
}
```

So I wanted to set some part of the class "shape" to class `Circle` but it kept giving me error:

> The Method `setRadius(int)` is undefined for the type `Shape`.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qayot.png)

Comment: Try to put warnings/errors inside the question rather than image

Comment: `Circle ci = new Circle(); ci.setRadius(2); sa[i] = ci;` (since all circles should have a radius, I would add that as a parameter to its constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to the fundamental concept of **Inheritance** in Object Oriented Programming.

You declare a `Shape` array, and this means that you can only use the methods defined in the `Shape` class while accessing an element, even if that item is an inherited type like, in your case, `Circle`

So the issue is that the `Shape` class does not define a method for `setRadius(int radius)` and thus, the method cannot be used when the variable is `Shape`

Perhaps you were after something like this?

```java
Circle[] circleArray = new Circle[10];

for (int i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i += 2)
{
    circleArray[i] = new Circle();
    circleArray[i].setRadius(2);
}
```